# don't understand few lines ruby codes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a ruby on rails project which is developed by someone else rails expert. I don't know ruby well. So while i modifying the existing project, i could not fix a bug because i didnt understand few lines code. It will be great if someone explain. Here are the codes -

## on my home controller - home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  menu_default :overview
  menu_specific :contact, :contact
```

## on my application controller - application.rb

```
  # report the current menu to the application helper, when forming
  # tabs
  def current_menu
    # work out the action of the current request
    action = request.path_parameters['action']

    # set the default
    menu_id = self.class.menu_structure[:default]

    # any specific ?
    menu_id = self.class.menu_structure[:specifics][action] unless self.class.menu_structure[:specifics].nil? or self.class.menu_structure[:specifics][action].nil?
    menu_id
  end

 def self.menu_default menu_id

    # default the menu
    @@menu ||= {}
    # work out the controller this relates to
    self.menu_structure[:default] = menu_id
  end

  def self.menu_specific menu_id, actions
    # turn the actions into an array
    actions = [actions] unless actions.is_a?(Array)

    # enumerate actions and setup
    actions.each do |action|
      self.menu_structure[:specifics] ||= {}
      self.menu_structure[:specifics][action.to_s] = menu_id
    end
  end

  def self.menu_structure
    controller = self.to_s
    @@menu ||= {}
  end
```

## on my application helper - application_helper.rb

```
  # page tab helper
  def tab menu_id, title, location
    # ask the application controller which is the current location

    # form the link with the appropriate class
    link = link_to title, location
    if( menu_id == controller.current_menu )
      content_tag("div", link, :class=>"menu_selected" )
    else
      content_tag("div", link, :class=>"menu_open" )
    end
  end
```

## on my layout - main.haml

```
= tab :overview,        "Overview", overview_url
```

I stuck for days. Please help me out. 
Thanks

Comment: What's the bug? What's the error?

Comment: there is a lot of stuff going here, what don't you get ?

Answer (score 2):

Rails can seem somewhat impenetrable without a good reference book. While there are many on the market, I found the Pragmatic Bookshelf to produce some of the best Ruby and Rails specific ones (http://www.pragprog.com/titles).

While Ruby is fairly straightforward to understand, Rails can take longer to fully absorb because there are a number of conventions that may be unfamiliar. Depending on your background, you may not have had much experience with a MVC-type design, or with object oriented programming in general, so those aspects can be a bit bewildering at first.